# Javascript in C# Issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am not sure why, but I am getting issues with a Javascript alert inside of an ASP application within the PageLoad() function. It processes fine, but when I try another action I get the following error (This also  only occurs in IE and Visual Studio (in debug mode) ) :

```
Line: 4056
Error: Unspecified error.

   Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert(' You currently have an incomplete quote.\\n Here is your customers information: \\n First Name: " + _firstName + " \\n Last Name: " + _lastName+ " \\n Number Of Drivers: " + _driveList.Count().ToString() + " \\n Number Of Vehicles: " + _vehicleList.Count().ToString() + " \\n Date Of Quote: " + _pendingQuote.Date.ToString()  + " ')</script>");
```

Comment: Is that error generated by visual studio or the browser?  By the time you get to that point in your code, is the response stream closed?

Comment: can you post your C# code that writes that?

Comment: Don't use string concatenation in this case. Use String.Format.

Comment: That error is in the browser only. If I close the alert box and continue working inside the application I receive that error. Visual studio debug gives me this: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: " but lists nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why dont you use script manager

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertScript", string.Format("alert('{0}');",alertText ), true);
```

and create Alert text from string builder like

```
    StringBuilder buildAlertString=new StringBuilder();
    buildAlertString.Append("You currently have an incomplete quote.");
    buildAlertString.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    buildAlertString.Append(string.Format("First Name:{0}",_firstName));
    ...
    string alertText=buildAlertString.ToString()
```

This is much easier to read and format. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert(' You currently have an incomplete quote.\\n Here is your customers information: \\n First Name: " + "FNAME" + " \\n Last Name: " + "LNAME"+ " \\n Number Of Drivers: " + 6 + " \\n Number Of Vehicles: " + 6 + " \\n Date Of Quote: " + "DATE"  + " ');</script>");
```

Then Try:

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert(' You currently have an incomplete quote.| Here is your customers information: | First Name: " + "FNAME" + " | Last Name: " + "LNAME"+ " | Number Of Drivers: " + 6 + " | Number Of Vehicles: " + 6 + " | Date Of Quote: " + "DATE"  + " ');</script>");
```